# OpenGL + GLUT Spot light

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glut, lighting

I'm having a bit of trouble creating a nice spot light. So far, my lighting properties are like this :

```
    /* Spot light */
glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
GLfloat ambientColor[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambientColor);

//Light
GLfloat lightColor0[] = {0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f,0.0f};
GLfloat lightPos0[] = {0.0f, 3.0f, 0.8f, 0.0};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, lightColor0);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor0);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, lightPos0);

glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 15.0);
GLfloat spot_direction[] = { 0.0, -1.0, 0.0 };
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, spot_direction);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 1.0);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 2.0);
```

I'm getting a 'spot light' of sorts... at least, its a light that sits above my scene and shines down on the objects, but its not (as far as I can tell) appearing in a conical sort of way. 
**This is the scene I'm trying to create**

[image: Target Scene]

**And here's what I've got so far**. [image: Result so far] 

I know my textures are a little buggered too, if any one could help with that as well, that'd be great!

Comment: how large is your scene? should the cutoff be so large?

Comment: How would I define the scene size? isn't the cutoff value the angle the radius of the spotlight cone?

Comment: You should know the position of your elements , most likely. The cutoff is the angle value... maybe if you move your light lower or reduce the cutoff you'll get the desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is here

[C++ Opengl - lighting using spotlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893332/c-opengl-lighting-using-spotlight?rq=1)

you need the last value of the position variable to be 1.0 for the light to be a spotlight.

Comment: Also, it likely is this way because the implementation of a spot light likely requires [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates).